# Difference between Producer/Consumer pattern and Observer Pattern

Tags: java, multithreading, design-patterns

I would like to understand the difference between the Observer Pattern and the most common problem of Producer/Consumer , Since both require synchronization so that the changes are available , and How do i go implement both ( if they are different )

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The difference between them is the nature of synchronization required.

In case of observer pattern whenever a change of interest is made in observed object all observers are notified immediately. So immediate per change synchronization is required by the pattern. In fact observer patterns doesn't require a different thread. The thread which is changing observed object can notify all registered observers.

However, in case of producer-consumer the only required synchronization is consumer must wait when there is no element and producer must wait when the buffer is full. But per object synchronization is not required. Producer can produce multiple objects before consumer consume any of them and consumer can consume multiple objects in one go. So immediate notification like observer is not needed here.

As far as the implementation, you can have a look at Wikipedia articles for them: [Observer Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) and [Producer-Consumer Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation , I have question :- Is it possible to apply both the concepts in single java program ?

Comment: Why not? The real world applications are so big that they can apply dozens of concepts like these in a single program.

Answer (score 0):

A producer consumer problem can be considered as an example of the observer pattern.